# Javascript validation: Return false not working, form still submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm using javascript for form validation but after submitting and the code returning false  the form still submits. I used the 'fixes' in other topics I found but the form still submits.

Here is my code:

```
function CheckFormi() {
    var lh = document.getElementById('op').value;
    var ph = document.getElementById('oc').value;
    var lb = document.getElementById('dp').value;

    if (lh == "País" || ph == "Codiga postal" || lb == "País") {
        if (lf == "País") {
            document.getElementById('op').style.border = "solid 1px #FF0000";
        }
        if (ph == "Codiga postal") {
            document.getElementById('oc').style.border = "solid 1px #FF0000";
        }
        if (lb == "País") {
            document.getElementById('dp').style.border = "solid 1px #FF0000";
        }
        alert('error');
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('a').submit();
    }
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post" id="a" onsubmit="return CheckFormi()">\
```

Any help will be appreciated,

thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the check works, it does show the alert but then still proceeds

Answer (score 1):

You have an error at this line :

```
if (lf == "País") {
```

variable `lf` may not exist (`lh` may be ?). That could explain why your alert is not displayed.

Comment: Hey dooxe, thank you, that solved! What a stupid mistake there. What threw me off was that the alert was actually displaying. Thanks a lot for your sharp eye!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use 'event.preventDefault();' instead of 'return false;'. in ie, you should use event.returnValue = false;.